# SSH : connect to host 192.xx port 22: connection refused

Tags: networking, 18.04, ssh, lan

I have 18.04 two PCs connected through LAN cable. I am able to ping PC2 from PC1. But when I try SSH to PC@ I get the following error

```
ssh agd@192.168.1.211
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.211 port 22: Connection refused
```

PC2 has static IP configured. And when I try to SSH to PC2 through WiFi, it works.

Referring a few guides on other threads, I tried

```
sudo service ssh status
```

All good, it is running an listening to port 22

Then I tried

```
sudo apt-get purge openssh-server 
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

That too went well. Listening to port 22 when checked the status.

Then I tried

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

All good

Then tried on both PCs

```
ufw allow 22
```

Tried and changed the port to `2222 in etc>ssh > sshd_config`

It is still listening to port 22 even after a restart.

Still no luck. Most of the other guides are old. I am using 18.04. If anyone can help with is, will be thankful.

In short, I am trying to use PC2 as a storage PC or my NAS ( not exactly)

PS : I cannot see the PC2 shared folders in `PC1 > Nautilus > Other locations`

Answer (score 1):

The issue was mainly the basic requirement for a LAN connection between 2 PC. PC1 too need a static IP just as PC2. I had to fix that in PC1 LAN adapter.

Once we do that, all we need to is connect the LAN cable between PCs and shared folders will be available.

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to connect to you router's IP Address instead of the server machine. Try using the `ip addr` which will be displaying your machine's ip address below `link/ether` in the second section. After that just copy and paste it and run `ssh username@ServerIP` like you have originally done.

Comment: No sir. I am using the static IP I gave to PC2. It works when using WiFi network. Since it is slow, I am trying to use LAN cable.

Comment: Perhaps your LAN IP is different than your Wifi's? check eth0 with ip addr

Comment: I manually added this particular static IP to the wired connection in PC2.

Comment: Did you try an SSH connection? Has it worked?

Comment: Yes, SSH Working with WiFi.